# How to create unit tests which runs only when manually specified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I remember something like '**explicit**', and google says that nunit has such attribute. 
Does **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting** provide something like this?

Comment: Also as an option is to create 2 test projects - 1 for one-time tests and 1 for regular tests

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MSTest tools does not explicitly support this type of behavior at an attribute level.  At the attribute level you can either enable a test via the `TestMethod` attribute or completely disable it with the `Ignore` attribute.  Once the `Ignore` attribute is added, mstest will not run the test until it is removed.  You cannot override this behavior via the UI.

What you can do though is disable the test via the property page.  Open up the test list editor, select the test you want and hit F4 to bring up the property page.  Set the Test Enabled property to false.  The test will now not run until you re-enable it through the property page.  It's not exactly what you're looking for but likely the closest equivalent.

Comment: Do you know, where this is stored? .csproj or .suo?

Comment: @Sergey, I do not know but my guess is the .suo file

Comment: @Sergey: this Test Enabled property is stored in a solution-level `.vsmdi` file

Comment: it stores information in SolutionName.vsmdi (Microsoft Visual Studio test meta data file) and in this way all developers can have same settings using svn.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a "Run Manually" category for your tests using the Category attribute, and then exclude that category from your tests in the GUI. These tests will be grayed out, and you can put them back in whenever you want. I do this often for slow-running tests.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, and it looks pretty old (Mar 2008), but I see that [TestListGenerator](http://www.codeplex.com/testlistgenerator) claims to auto-generate [Test Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182461%28VS.80%29.aspx) based on attributes you set on your tests. If it works, this would effectively provide [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10) for MS Test. While not the same as [Explicit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=explicit&r=2.2.10), it may let you achieve what you want.