# Listing test results in VS2010 that DONT include a keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, testcase

Is there any way I can filter test results by specifying a keyword that should NOT appear?

**Context:**

I've written some C# classes and methods, but did not implement those methods for now (I made them throw a NotImplementedException so that they clearly indicate this). I also written some test cases for those functions, but they currently fail because the methods throw the NotImplementedException. This is ok and I expect this for now.

I want to ignore these tests for now and look at other test results that are more meaningful, so I was trying to figure out how I can list results that do not have the "NotImplementedException". However, I can only list the results that do have that keyword, not those that don't. Is there any way I can list the results that don't? Using some wildcards or something?

I see a lot of information about the new Test Explorer in VS2012, but that's not a feature in 2010, which is what I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of cheat to pass this tests, if you want to, by marking that this test expects an exception to be thrown and thereby passes the test.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NotImplementedException))]
public void NotYetImplementedMethod(Object args)
{
    ....
}
```

Alternatively you can create categories for your tests. This way you can choose which tests to run in the Test explorer, if you assign a category to most of your tests.

```
[TestMethod]
[Testcategory("NotImplementedNotTested")]
public void NotYetImplementedMethod(Object args)
{
    ....
}
```

Last but not least the simplest solution `[Ignore]`. This will skip the tests alltogether.

```
[TestMethod]
[Ignore]
public void NotYetImplementedMethod(Object args)
{
    ....
}
```

Reference:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Getting-Started-with-Unit-Testing-Part-1
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Getting-Started-with-Unit-Testing-Part-2
- [How to create unit tests which runs only when manually specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223338/how-to-create-unit-tests-which-runs-only-when-manually-specified)

Comment: These are great, I didn't know there were ways of categorizing and ignoring test cases. This is a good workaround for this if it turns out that there is no way of filtering. Though I'd rather not have to modify the test code.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for is not possible in VS2010, so I'm marking this as an answer because it's a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

> I also written some test cases for those functions

If your tests are linked to `Test Case`s work items on TFS you could simply set the Test Case's State to `Design`. Then, on your `Test Plans` exclude all test cases that are on `Designed` state.

If they are not linked to actual Test Cases work items (let's say a batch of unit tests), I believe the best solution is the `Ignore` attrbute (as @Serv already mentioned). Because I don't think you want to run tests that are not implemented yet and also waste time to find out how to exclude them from test results.

Comment: The tests are implemented. The actual class it's testing is not, and it throws a NotImplementedException, which fails the test. Also, I'm not using TFS

Comment: Even so, if you use [TFS Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5(v=vs.100).aspx) (User Stories, Test Cases, Test Plans etc, all linked together), you can create `Requirement bases Test Plan`s and exclude the User Stories that are implemented. If not, then use the `Ignore` attribute.